# Get Source (or <tcm:PublisherScript>) of Component Template via Core Service?

Tags: 2013, core-service, 2013-sp1

I'm using the code  below to loop through CTs.  I want to get the XML in the source tab.  I can see it in the  node if I look at the full XML block for the CT, but how can I get it from the ComponentTemplateData object?  Do I need to call GetListXML instead?

```
var ro = new ReadOptions();
String[] pubs = new String[]{"tcm:0-1-1"};
foreach(String s in pubs){  
var pub = Tridion.Read(s, ro);
//Component Templates
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[]{ItemType.ComponentTemplate};
var list = Tridion.GetList(s, filter);

foreach(var item in list){
    ctb=(ComponentTemplateData)item;

    Debug.WriteLine(ctb.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `componenttemplatedataobject.Content` to get the xml as in the source tab. In your example if you use `ctb.Content` it will give you the xml as in the source tab

Comment: The Content property is already a string, so no need for a .ToString() on it

Comment: Not sure if Content comes prepopulated from a GetList() call; you might need `ctb = (ComponentTemplateData)Tridion.Read(ctb.Id, ro)`

Comment: @DavidForster removed it

Comment: @BjørnvanDommelen Correct. The content won't be loaded from the GetList call's IdentifiableObjects

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  So GetList() returns IdentifiableObjects, which just contains some basic descriptive info and read returns the specific object.